# Where can I access request parameters in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and python-requests and passing several variables through the URL as shown below.

```
GET /api/boxobjects/?format=json&make=Prusa&model=i3&plastic=PLA HTTP/1.1
```

I'm passing the variables make, model, and plastic. The recommended method to access these parameters is shown below.

```
makedata = request.GET.get('make', '')
```

However, I have no idea where to place that line of code. I've completed the tutorial for Django Rest Framework and have my views set up to roughly match the tutorial.

`views.py`:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@login_required
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'Users': reverse('api:user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'Objects': reverse('api:object-list', request=request, format=format),
        'Files': reverse('api:file-list', request=request, format=format),
        'Config Files': reverse('api:config-list', request=request, format=format),
        'Box-objects': reverse('api:box-object-list', request=request, format=format),
    })

class BoxViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Uploadobject.objects.all().exclude(verified=False)
    serializer_class = BoxSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                            IsBox)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    #Maybe get function here? Not displaying
    '''
    def get(self, request):
        print ("request set here?")
    '''
```

Where would I place the one line of code to access these request parameters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
class BoxViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Uploadobject.objects.all().exclude(verified=False)
    serializer_class = BoxSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                            IsBox)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


    def get_queryset(self):
        req = self.request
        print(req)
        make = req.query_params.get('make')
        if make:
            self.queryset = uploadobject.objects.filter(make=make)
            return self.queryset
        else:
            return self.queryset
```

What is the statement doing ?

If `'make'` is in the query params of the request then overwrite the `BoxViewSet` queryset property with a new queryset based on `'make'` and return it. otherwise return the default queryset that excludes any objects that isn't verified.

Comment: This works perfect! So good in fact, it works without the if/else statement. For bonus points, what does that statement do?

Answer (score 9):

Based on Django Rest Framework's [Filtering Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/), there are two ways to access parameters from a request.

## 1. URL Params

If you are using URL params (such as `mywebapp.com/api/<user_slug>/resource/`), you can access the arguments like this: `self.kwargs['param_name']` where `param_name` is the name of the parameter you're trying to get the value for. So for the example above, you'd have `user_slug = self.kwargs['user_slug']`

## Example from the documentation

**If your URL structure looks like this:**

```
url('^purchases/(?P<username>.+)/$', PurchaseList.as_view()),
```

**...and want to filter on that username. You can override the get_queryset() and your view will look like this:**

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Purchase.objects.filter(purchaser__username=username)
```

## 2. Query Params

If you are using query parameters such as `mywebapp.com/api/resource?user_slug=plain-jane`, you can use `self.request` to access `request` as you can in plain vanilla Django REST methods. This gives you access to things like `self.request.query_params`. For the example above, you would say `user_slug = self.request.query_params['user_slug']`. You can also access the current user like `user = self.request.user`.

## Example from the documentation

**Let's say you want to support a request structure like this:**

```
http://example.com/api/purchases?username=denvercoder9
```

**...and want to filter on that username. Do this to override the queryset:**

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

## Django 2

Use **request.parser_context**

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        post_id = self.request.parser_context['kwargs'].get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        serializer.save(post=post)
```

Answer (score 0):

adding a little to what they have already contributed, for the POST methods in modelviewset when an object is sent, it is necessary to use `request.data['myvariable']`

example:

```
class BoxViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Uploadobject.objects.all().exclude(verified=False)
    serializer_class = BoxSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                        IsBox)

    def create(self, request):
       ...
       make = request.data['make']
```